# How to get section heading of tables in wikipedia through API

Tags: wikipedia-api

How do I get section headings for individual tables: `Xia dynasty (夏朝) (2070–1600 BC)`, `Shang dynasty (商朝) (1600–1046 BC)`, `Zhou dynasty (周朝) (1046–256 BC)` etc. for the Chinese Monarchs list on Wikipedia via API? I use the code below to connect:

```py
from pprint import pprint
import requests, wikitextparser

r = requests.get(
    'https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php',
    params={
        'action': 'query',
        'titles': 'List_of_Chinese_monarchs',
        'prop': 'revisions',
        'rvprop': 'content',
        'format': 'json',
    }
)
r.raise_for_status()
pages = r.json()['query']['pages']
body = next(iter(pages.values()))['revisions'][0]['*']
doc = wikitextparser.parse(body)
print(f'{len(doc.tables)} tables retrieved')

han = doc.tables[5].data()
doc.tables[6].data()
```

`doc.tables[i].data()` only return the table values, without its `<h2>` section headings. I would like the API to return me a list of title strings that correspond to each of the 83 tables returned.

## Original website:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Chinese_monarchs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure why you are using doc.tables when it is the sections you are interested in. This works for me:

```
for i in range(1,94,1):
    print(doc.sections[i].title.replace('[[','').replace(']]',''))
```

I get 94 sections though rather than 83 and while you can use len(doc.sections) this will include See also etc. There must be a more elegant way of removing the wikilinks.